# Find patients admitted multiple times for the same primary diagnosis in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

Need help with the below SQL query.
Problem statement - Show patient_id, primary_diagnosis from admissions. Find patients admitted multiple times for the same primary_diagnosis

Table - admissions
Table headers - patient_id, admission_date, discharge_date, primary_diagnosis, secondary_diagnosis

My code -

```
SELECT Distinct ad1.patient_id, ad1.primary_diagnosis
FROM admissions ad1 join admissions ad2
ON ad1.patient_id = ad2.patient_id AND
ad1.primary_diagnosis = ad2.primary_diagnosis
Group by ad1.patient_id
having count(ad1.patient_id)>1;
```

I was solving the problem online and the above code is not giving me the desired output.
The portal doesn't tell what is wrong with the code.
Please correct me if I am making a mistake in the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like writing a self join statement is unnecessary when you already have Group by and Having statement. Like the previous answer says, make sure to group by both patient_id and primary_diagnosis since you need to know what the same patient was diagnosed with (primary_diagnosis).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  ad.patient_id,
  ad.primary_diagnosis
FROM
  admissions ad
GROUP BY
  ad.patient_id,
  ad.primary_diagnosis
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT ad.admission_date) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work

```
select 
patient_id,
primary_diagnosis 
from admissions
group by patient_id, primary_diagnosis
having count (primary_diagnosis)>1
```

Comment: While This May Answer The Question, Your Answer is unclear to future readers who may not have the exact Database Structure. Please Consider Adding An Explanation For Your SQL Query & Citation Sources Always Improve the Answer's Quality. Please Also Consider Reading: [How Do I Write A Good Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  patient_id,
  primary_diagnosis
FROM admissions
GROUP BY
  patient_id,
  primary_diagnosis
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: What is the advantage over counting `DISTINCT admission_date` or `primary_diagnosis`?